# Cordova : network-information plugin not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am not able to run network-information plugin in cordova properly in fresh Cordova project, My system info

```
node -v : v0.10.29
cordova -v  : 3.5.0-0.2.6
ubuntu 13.10
```

I tried installing plugin in both way

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.cordova-plugin-network-information
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information
```

When I run I am getting following log in logcat

```
W/System.err(10746): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.network-information.NetworkManager
W/System.err(10746):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err(10746):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
W/System.err(10746):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
W/System.err(10746):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.getClassByName(PluginEntry.java:117)
W/System.err(10746):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:93)
W/System.err(10746):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:281)
W/System.err(10746):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:232)
W/System.err(10746):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
W/System.err(10746):    at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
W/System.err(10746):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
W/System.err(10746):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
W/System.err(10746):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:92)
W/System.err(10746):    at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:108)
W/System.err(10746):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(10746):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
W/System.err(10746):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1092)
W/System.err(10746):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

W/System.err(10746): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cordova/network-information/NetworkManager
W/System.err(10746):    ... 17 more
W/System.err(10746): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.cordova.network-information.NetworkManager" on path: /data/app/com.app-16.apk
W/System.err(10746):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
W/System.err(10746):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
W/System.err(10746):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
W/System.err(10746):    ... 17 more
I/System.out(10746): Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.network-information.NetworkManager.
I/Web Console(10746): Error initializing Network Connection: Class not found:85
```

I tried to add and remove android platform and plugins many times but this problem still persist.

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I google a lot about this question and found when we run `cordova run android` sometime it does not copy all files in appropriate folders and causes this problem of class not found. For for this I tried to give full permission to project folder and now its working seamlessly.